# javascript typeof item === "undefined" never returns true

Tags: javascript

In the following code sample, typeof item === "undefined" never returns true.  i am trying to get an attribute from XML, if the attribute is not there in the XML it returns "undefined", but i am not able to capture whether it has returned undefined or not, firebug shows "typeof item" as an "object"

```
var item;
var itemIDs = {};
if (items.status == 200)
{   
    var rows = items.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('z:row');
    for(i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    { 
        //rows[i].attr(attribute);
        item = rows[i].getAttribute(attribute);
        if(typeof item === "undefined")
        {
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
            item = item.match(/[^\d+;#][\w\W]+/);
            itemIDs[item] = 1 ;
        }

    }
}
else
{
     alert('There was an error: ' + items.statusText);
}

return itemIDs;
```

**Edit:** I changed the condition to if(item == undefined), The code now works as expected now

**Edit2:** Double checked it, item variable was never null , it was "undefined"

Comment: If `typeof x` is returning `"object"` then `x` could be an object or it could be `null`.  Alert `JSON.stringify(x)` to find out exactly what your item is!

Comment: @Ray Toal: I changed the code to if(item == undefined) it works now!

Comment: is it possible that the status is 200 but an empty list is returned for getElementsByTagName()? you're not trapping that possibility.

Comment: OK, glad you solved it! I didn't see your reply until after I'd posted the comment

Comment: But make sure you know way, @zer0c00l.  `==` is a mess in JavaScript. It equates a bunch of things you would not expect.  The value of item was not `undefined` here, it was (probably) `null` and `null == undefined`.  Ugh.  `hasAttribute` is the way to go.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx: No it is not an empty list

Comment: @Ray: `==` is **not** a mess, and it's frequently very handy. You do need to understand what it does, and what it does *is* complex. But it's not "a mess".

Comment: @zer0c00l: `undefined==null`, but `undefined!==null`

Comment: Really, `[] == null` is `false` in JavaScript

Comment: I'll stand by the mess comment, @TJ, agreeing that is handy (and knowing exactly its semantics).  But to me, IMHO, and it is fine if I am in the minority opinion, `0 == "  \r\t" is, yes, _to me, anyway_ a mess. :-)  Cheers.

Comment: @Ray: Yeah, that one is a bit out there. :-)

Comment: No @TJ, sorry the "empty list" was directed at the OP, who said "No it is not an empty list" which I misread as "No it is not; it is the empty list".  Sorry for the confusion.  Sorry to both of you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getAttribute returns an object (valid object or a null object). So the check `(typeof item === "undefined")` is not correct. It should be `(item === null)`.

Answer (score 2):

Some browser's implementation of `getAttribute` may return an empty string if the attribute doesn't exist.  You could test for both null and `""`, or alternatively use `hasAttribute`.

```
if(rows[i].hasAttribute(attribute))
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Comment: True, the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-666EE0F9) says it *should* always return an empty string.

Comment: I like your answer too, unfortunately i can accept only one :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's because `typeof null === 'object'` (contrary to the common sense). You should check if `getAttrbiute`'s return value equals `null`.

```
item = rows[i].getAttribute(attribute);
if (item == null) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: If you really want to check for null, use `===`.  Please! :-)

Comment: @Ray Toal, only `null == null` and `undefined == null`. So no, it's not necessary here. Thanks for your pedantry, though.

Comment: True indeed.  `==` is fine in this case.  Only in situations where null and undefined need to be distinguished does it really matter....

Answer (score 1):

`typeof null` is `"object"`... this is what getAttribute seems to return when the attribute is missing. See documentation of [element.getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute), specifically the [notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute#Notes) section. It is suggested that you can use [hasAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (!item)
{
    continue;
}
else
{
    item = item.match(/[^\d+;#][\w\W]+/);
    itemIDs[item] = 1 ;
}
```

this proofs if the item is null or undefined. is this true, it continues the loop.

Comment: this is only okay because of the getAttribute return type, otherwise it would perform unexpected results if `item` held a value of `0`

Comment: Or an empty string, if the code needs to differentiate between the attribute not being there and the attribute being blank.

Answer (score 0):

`getAttribute` : return type `object`

---

you should compare return value to `null`